# C# Read and Write objectname and object coordinate position

Tags: c#

i am doing some sort of animation that record the object position frame by frame. I want to save the frameNo, objectname and the object coordinate position x,y,z into textfile and i can able retrieve the data. What is the best way to implement it?

```
    palmTimer-=Time.time;
        if(palmTimer <= 0)
        {
            palmFrame +=1;
            Debug.Log (palmFrame);
            Debug.Log (palmObject);
            Debug.Log (palmObject.transform.localPosition);
            palmTimer =180.0f;
        }
```

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (text, coordinates, store, write) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a struct of some sort to store the data, then use an XML or JSON serializer to store and retrieve the data into an array of the structs.

```
struct FrameData
{
    public int FrameNumber;
    public string ObjectName;
    public int X, Y, Z;
    public FrameData(int frameNumber, string objectName, int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.FrameNumber = frameNumber; this.ObjectName = objectName; this.X = x;
        this.Y = y; this.Z = z;
    }
}
```

At each frame, store the data into a new FrameData object and put it into an array or a list. Then when finished, use a serializer to serialize the data.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrameData[]));
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fs, frameDataArray);
}
```

Then to get the data again:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrameData[]));
FrameData[] frameDataArray;
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open))
{
    frameDataArray = (FrameData[])serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

If XML serialization takes up too much space you could try using JSON instead. There are plenty of resources online to teach you about JSON serialization/deserialization, it's pretty similar to the XML version. I would recommend the Nuget library JSON.NET, it's good and simple.

Can't guarantee the code I wrote will work exactly as is, but it should hopefully point you in the right direction.